# Queue persistency on .Net

Tags: .net, persistence, queue

I have a Windows Service that uses System.Collections.Generic.Queue to keep some files that I'll process.

The problem is when my service fail, and if I restart the service, it looses the files that need to process.

How could I persist my queue? I was thinking if is it possible to serialize the queue and write it in a file. What do you think?

Comment: @mslot Hey thanks, I'll study it. Some interisting content : [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx) and [link(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3944/Programming-MSMQ-in-NET-Part-1) and part 2 - [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4348/Programming-MSMQ-in-NET-Part-2-Transactional-Messa)

Comment: Define fast. I would say it is pretty fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although serialize the queue as @the_joric said I also a good solution, I understand that Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ) will work better, and fit well to my case.

Answer (score 2):

you may serialize queue:

```
var queue = new Queue<string>();

queue.Enqueue("234");
queue.Enqueue("234");

var dataContractSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (Queue<string>));

const string outputFileName = "myfile.xml";
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(outputFileName))
{
    dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, queue);
}

var savedContent = File.ReadAllText(outputFileName);
Console.Out.WriteLine("savedContent = {0}", savedContent);
```